# Query to get different values depending on all column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table tasks with a status column The value of status can either be 0,1 or 2.

I need to implement the following logic:

- If any value in status is 0 then the answer is 0.
- If all values are 2 then the result is 2.
- Otherwise the result is one.

Right now I'm doing this with 3 queries.

```
a) SELECT status FROM tasks
b) SELECT status FROM tasks WHERE status = 2;
c) SELECT status FROM tasks WHERE status = 0
```

So a) is for getting the total number of rows. Then I compare that to the number of rows given by b). If the match then the answer is 2. If they don't I do query c). If it is non-empty the answer is 0 otherwise the answer is 1.

Is there any way to write a single query for this? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN s0 >= 1 THEN 0
          WHEN sAll = s2 THEN 2
          ELSE 1
        END
FROM (        
SELECT COUNT(*) AS sAll,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 END) AS s0,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS s2
FROM tasks ) t
```

The sub-query performs all counts required to apply your business logic. The outer query simply uses this info, to produce the required result.

It's a bit unclear from your description whether the first condition in the `CASE` takes precedence over the second. If not, then just switch the position of the two `WHEN`s.

Comment: Hi Giorgos , +1 but still your query got issue,  you need to modify 2nd last line to -> `COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 2 END) AS s2` .

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com The purpose of `COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN **1** END)` is to count all 2s. If I change `1` to `2` then `COUNT` will return `COUNT*2` and `sAll = s2` predicate will fail in the outer query.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Conditional aggregation works because `COUNT` *ignores* `NULL`s. Hence, `COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END)` counts exactly the number of rows having `status=2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT MIN(status) FROM tasks;
```

- since when all status values are 2, the minimum will be 2, when any value is 0 then the minimum will be 0 and otherwise the minimum wll be 1.

Comment: Technically, the first answer is the right one and I selected it as correct because that is the Idea I had. And I got to learn about coutn and case. However you are absolutely right. This would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
 SELECT (case 
when ((SELECT count(*) FROM tasks WHERE status = 0)>0) then 0 
when ((SELECT count(*) FROM tasks WHERE status = 2)=(SELECT count(*) FROM tasks)) then 2
else 1 end)  AS countOfStatus
```